# Как отменить изменения в AlertDialog.Builder?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Создаю диалоговое окно с множественным выбором. Подскажите, как правильно отменить изменения выбора после нажатия на кнопку Отмена или закрытия окна? Первое, что приходит в голову - записывать все изменения в массив, а потом подгружать их в зависимости от действий пользователя (нажатие на ок или отмену). Есть ли какой-то более удобный способ?

```
private void showEventParticipantsDialog()
{
    String[] listItems = new String[] {"Музыкант", "Музыкальная группа", "Фотограф", "Видеограф", "Фокусник",
            "Ведущий", "Шоу", "Диджей", "Звукорежиссёр", "Декоратор"};

    AlertDialog.Builder checkBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    checkBuilder.setTitle("Выберите участников");

    checkBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(listItems, participantsArray, (dialogInterface, i, b) ->
            participantsArray[i] = b);

    checkBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ок", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
        {

        }
    });

    checkBuilder.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
        {
            Log.d("SAHJASSA", "Cancel: ");
        }
    });

    checkBuilder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface)
        {
            Log.d("SAHJASSA", "onDismiss: ");
        }
    });

    checkBuilder.create();
    checkBuilder.show();
}
```

Comment: что отменять-то? окно открылось и закрылось

Comment: Открывается окно, пользователь ставит и убирает галки. Если нажать ок, то состояние галок сохраняется, если нажать отмена, восстанавливается на момент открытия окна.

Comment: если нажимается отмена, то значит все установки НЕ верны, зачем это сохранять? правильно не зачем.

Comment: @Style-7 посмотрите решение woesss. Он понял в чём была проблема.

Comment: это не решение, это у вас неправильный подход к задаче, впрочем поступайте как вам будет угодно

Comment: спасибо за совет)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно не трогать массив при кликах по элементам, а применить всё разом при позитивном клике.
Соответственно никакие изменения не будут применены если диалог закрыли любым другим способом:

```java
checkBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ок", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        SparseBooleanArray cip = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
        for (int i = 0; i < cip.size(); i++) {
            int key = cip.keyAt(i);
            participantsArray[key] = cip.get(key);
        }    
    }
});
```

P.S. Чтобы диалог не изменял входной массив нужно передать `null` вместо обработчика клика по элементу. Странно что это работает именно так, а не наоборот - но что имеем, то имеем:

```java
checkBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(listItems, participantsArray, null);
```

Comment: подскажите, как в этом случае выставлять значения которые были сохранены при клике на ок при повторном открытии окна? 
Если прописать так: checkBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(listItems, null, (dialogInterface, i, b) -> {});
все галочки всегда выключены при открытии окна.
А если указать checkBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(listItems, participantsArray, (dialogInterface, i, b) -> {}); не работает принцип с сохранением данных только при клике Ок.

Comment: Хм.. опять в доках ни слова о side-effect. Диалог самовольно изменяет переданный ему массив. Есть решение - смотрите дополнение в ответе

Comment: Так работает. Спасибо вам!)